# kernel upgrade causes ping to fail

Tags: linux, networking, dns, ping

I am facing some strange problem. I compiled the latest linux kernel and used "make localmodconfig" to create my .config file. In the new kernel "ping google.com" does not work. However the following works.
**NSLOOKUP google.com** works, **DIG google.com** works, **host google.com** works. Similarly giving ifconfig after "ping google.com" shows increase in TX and RX counters. So it looks to me like packets are received. **SELinux** is disabled and **iptables** does not have rules.

Contents of /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 4.2.2.2
```

Ping by IP works. For example, if I ping the IP address of google, I am getting response. The name servers are also pingable.

Can someone please help me out.

Thanks

Chid

Comment: Sounds like `nsswitch.conf` may be incorrect.

Comment: Is it just `google.com` which gives you a problem or you can not ping other places as well?

Comment: Any address with host name cannot be pinged. If I "nslookup" the host name and ping the IP, I am able to ping. Curl / wget also does not work

Comment: @DavidSchwartz : Thanks. I went over a couple of forums which suggested the issue could be in nsswitch.conf. Unfortunately my file is same as specified in those forums.